Why is my fluid sim in blender ignoring my obstacle mesh from unreal (megascan asset)?
So im doing a little creek thing planning on having flowing water eventually, but at the moment have run into a problem with the mesh I brought into blender from UE5 using megascans.
Im using the FLIP fluids addon for blender 4.1, ive tried adding a solidifier modifier this did not work, and I've double checked normals. Yes, there are a couple of cracks in the creek bed since it is made up from multiple megascan assets, was thinking that wouldnt matter though?
I did attempt to try and remesh it but blender crashed so I thought Id ask around before trying to get that to work.
Really bummed about this so any help would be much appreciated!!


